# Burninate the [low-priority] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, meta-tags, burninate-request

The meta-tag, [low-priority](/questions/tagged/low-priority) seems to be pointless for a few reasons:

- If it is *so* low of a priority, is it worth asking?
- It isn't obvious who can make the decision of its priority.
- It may be an actual problem for someone else.
- Does this tag add anything of substance? Would anything change without it?
- There are **only 7** questions with this tag.

Can this tag be removed?

Comment: Hmm, is this high-priority?

Comment: @Bart I almost tagged this question as low-priority...

Comment: Does low-priority necessarily refer to the question itself? Couldn't it be about low-priority processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I edited the seven questions with the tag to remove it (and make any other worthwhile changes).  It will be automatically removed as an orphan in ~24 hours.

For an obvious meta-tag tag with so little use, I'm not sure anyone really needs to ask for burnination versus just editing it away themselves.

Comment: Checking Meta for burnination is always a good idea if you think anyone might care, or there are more than a few dozen questions and people might notice.